# How to change the property of a nested component in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I use MudBlazor and want to change shadow of Menu item.
In MudMenu.razor i see next syntax:

```
...
 <MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" Class="@PopoverClass" MaxHeight="@MaxHeight" AnchorOrigin="@AnchorOrigin" TransformOrigin="@TransformOrigin" RelativeWidth="@FullWidth" Style="@PopoverStyle" @ontouchend:stopPropagation>
        <CascadingValue Value="@this">
            <MudList Class="@ListClass" Clickable="true" Dense="@Dense"  
                @onmouseenter="@MouseEnter"
                @onmouseleave="@MouseLeave">
                @ChildContent
            </MudList>
        </CascadingValue>
    </MudPopover>
...
```

In MudPopover.razor.cs i see the property for default elevation:

```
...
        [Parameter]
        [Category(CategoryTypes.Popover.Appearance)]
        public int Elevation { set; get; } = 8;
...
```

So, if i make new Razor component in cs-file like this:

```
public class MyMenu : MudMenu
```

i still can`t change property of MudPopover inside.
What is right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should create a new Razor component file for your custom menu, let's call it `MyMenu.razor`:

```
@inherits MudMenu

<MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" Class="@PopoverClass" MaxHeight="@MaxHeight" AnchorOrigin="@AnchorOrigin" TransformOrigin="@TransformOrigin" RelativeWidth="@FullWidth" Style="@PopoverStyle" Elevation="@MyElevation" @ontouchend:stopPropagation>
    <CascadingValue Value="@this">
        <MudList Class="@ListClass" Clickable="true" Dense="@Dense" @onmouseenter="@MouseEnter" @onmouseleave="@MouseLeave">
            @ChildContent
        </MudList>
    </CascadingValue>
</MudPopover>
```

Then, in the file for your custom menu, `MyMenu.razor.cs`, add a new property `MyElevation` that you can use to customize the elevation value:

```
public class MyMenuBase : MudMenu
{
    [Parameter]
    public int MyElevation { get; set; } = 8;
}
```

And now you can use your custom menu component, `MyMenu`, in your application:

```
<MyMenu MyElevation="12">
    <!-- Add your menu items here -->
</MyMenu>
```